# Printing data in listview to firebase

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I asked this before but no one could answer. Thanks in advance to the person who can help.

```
<Grid>

        <ListView x:Name="lstOrder">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <ViewCell>

                        <Grid>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="{Binding OrderName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" x:Name="lblName"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding OrderCount}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" x:Name="lblStepperValue"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding OrderDetail}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" x:Name="edtDetail"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding OrderPrice}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" x:Name="lblPriceNormal"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

        <Button BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="End" Text="Sipariş ver" x:Name="giveOrder" Clicked="giveOrder_Clicked"/>

    </Grid>
```

This way I have a simple list view. And data is sent from realmDB to this list view. I want to send the data sent from RealmDB to this list view to my Firebase database when the button is clicked.

I don't want to write data to listview via firebase.

What I want to do is print the data in listview to firebase.

This is like printing the text on a label to firebase. I want to print the data from listview to firebase.

This is my button's code block. So when I press this button, the data in listview will be written to firebase.

that is, it will send the data on the labels to firebase.

```
private async void giveOrder_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await firebaseHelper.AddDoner(lstOrder.**!I can't do this part!**);
    }
```

Hopefully it's revealing enough.

Thanks :)

This is the part I wrote for firebase, I wonder if there could be a mistake here?

```
public class FirebaseHelper
{
    readonly FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("my firebase link");

    public async Task<List<DonerModel>> GetAllDoners()
    {
        return (await firebase
          .Child("Doners")
          .OnceAsync<DonerModel>()).Select(item => new DonerModel
          {
              OrderList = item.Object.OrderList
          }).ToList();
    }
    public async Task AddDoner( string lstOrder)
    {

        await firebase
          .Child("Doners")
          .PostAsync(new DonerModel() { OrderList = lstOrder});
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tG5s.png)

Comment: however you set the ItemsSource for your ListView, you would use that same data to "send" the data to Firebase.

Comment: I've already set item source for list view, but still can't send data from listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of objects that have been bound to the ListView you can use the [ItemSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.itemsview-1.itemssource?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ItemsView_1_ItemsSource) property.

Another point to note is that if you need the exact type (Order in your example) you can do something like this

```
private async void giveOrder_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(lstOrder.ItemsSource != null && lstOrder.ItemsSource is List<OrderRealm> orders)
    {
        //send orders to firebase
        foreach(var order in orders)
        {
             await firebaseHelper.AddDoner(order.*field you want to add to firebase*);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but could not come to a valid result. Can you help a little more?

Comment: could you describe your issues you are now facing?

Comment: When I use the code block you sent, I can send my data in listview to firebase, right?

Comment: I have been trying to learn Xamarini for the last few months and I am not able to learn much, normally I was trying to do something with python android studio.

Comment: `public BasketPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var realmDB = Realm.GetInstance();
            var myItemSource = realmDB.All<OrderRealm>().ToList();
            lstOrder.ItemsSource = myItemSource;
        }
        private async void giveOrder_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {   
            if (lstOrder.ItemsSource != null && lstOrder.ItemsSource is List<Order> orders)
            {
                //send orders to firebase
                await firebaseHelper.AddDoner(orders);
            }
        }`

Comment: I also added a photo for you to see more comfortably.

Comment: I don't know how to do this part and I can't find a place to look and learn as an example. Nobody asked a question like this before seems like a difficult topic

Comment: so two things to add you need to import the collections namespace and rename ORder to OrderRealm I have updated my code snippet

Comment: As I said already you are missing an import for the collections namespace. that is your latest issue. If you hover over the issue it will give you an option to import it.

Comment: yes i missed i apologize but i have a different problem now and I added a new photo

Comment: i have updated my answer, you must select what property from the realmOrder you wish to add to firebase. this will hopefully solve your issues.